# Security of $_SESSION array

Tags: php, security, session

When a low-privilege non-administrator user logs into my web app successfully, I am storing the following data in the `$_SESSION` array:

```
$_SESSION = array(
    'user_id'     => 2343,  // whatever their user_id number is from the DB
    'allow_admin' => false, // don't give them access to admin tools
    'allow_edit'  => false, // don't let them edit stuff
    );
```

Is there any way that they could manipulate the `$_SESSION` array to give them Admin or Edit access, apart from somehow editing the session files in `/tmp`? (The above code is the only place where those items are added to `$_SESSION`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The contents of the session are only visible and modifiable on the server side.

They could only be modified in an "unauthorized" way if your application or server contains some vulnerability.

You should also be aware of such things as [session fixation attacks](http://shiflett.org/articles/session-fixation), where an attacker forces a particular session id onto an unsuspecting user, who when logs in and elevates that session's privileges, allowing an attacker to share that session.

One approach to mitigating these is to [regenerate the session id](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php) whenever you change privilege levels of the session.

See also this question:

- [PHP Session Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328/php-session-security)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to avoid javascript reading your cookies and man in the middle attacks, you need to use a server with https and set the session cookie to only be transported over https.

session.cookie_secure specifies whether cookies should only be sent over secure connections. Defaults to off. This setting was added in PHP 4.0.4. See also session_get_cookie_params() and session_set_cookie_params().

session.cookie_httponly Marks the cookie as accessible only through the HTTP protocol. This means that the cookie won't be accessible by scripting languages, such as JavaScript. This setting can effectively help to reduce identity theft through XSS attacks (although it is not supported by all browsers).

To secure admin privileges better for someone leaving his computer unguarded for a few mins, you should have a timer on last (admin) login. If that time is more then x timeunits away, the user has to login again to use admin rights.

Shorter sessions are also more secure then longer ones.

Answer (score 3):

### Server

**Sessions** are stored on the server. A user could change session data if they have direct access to the directory where sessions are stored. A solution to this is to secure the directory. And make sure you don't have a hole in your php code where you allow the user_id to be set by a $_POST or $_GET.

### Client

But on the client side manipulating sessions is **possible** by [hijacking](http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/4.html) someones session_id. This will let the hijacker pose as that user. And send request on their behalf.

There is also **Cross-Site Request Forgery**. This is when a hacker tricks a user into sending requests for [him](http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/2.html). By making him click on a link for example. You could combat this with tokens. A token is a generated string that is put in the $_SESSION array and in every HTML form as a hidden field. When the user submits a form the values are checked against each other. And every time the user requests a new page the token changes. This way an attacker must try to predict the token, which is pretty hard depending on how you make the token.

The links will also show examples on these attacks.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't provide such access in your script there isn't much users can do about that. So your session data should be pretty secure. The only thing user can do is to manipulate session cookie or session id passed in the URL but it's unlikely that he will find an existing session id of another user.

Answer (score 1):

Not unless you've left a security hole somewhere (such as allowing users to add/change $_SESSION data somehow).

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, no, unless user guess your session id and replaces it in his cookies. You should add additional IP-check at least server-side to prevent this.