# Session handling in PHP

Tags: php, session, security

What is the best & most secure way you've handled sessions in a PHP application? I want to know the best, most robust and secure method there is. :)

Comment: Try this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/328/php-session-security

Comment: Ah, thanks Paul. That's a good thread. Someone can close this thread. I've got what I've wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your session data will be pretty safe. If you want to make it even safer, encrypt it. Beyond that, you'll have to be more explicit about what you desire.

Answer (score 1):

That would depend on your environment. If your using a shared host, it maybe possible for others customers hosted on the same box to access you session data. If that's the case, it might be safer to store it in a database. But every server is different. Can you elaborate on your setup, and what your trying to protect against?

Comment: Basically, I'm going to develop a web application and want to know whether there are any recommended rules for handling sessions to make it robust and powerful. I believe the link Paul mentioned (look up) has the answers, though I haven't gone through all the answers. Thank you for your answer too. :)