# Codeigniter: Userdata--When/Why/How to use

Tags: php, codeigniter

When is the proper time to use userdata?  Why is it good/not good?  And how should I use it properly?

When is it bad/not conventional to use?

Specifically, what's the best convention/method to utilize the session class:
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: What exactly do you mean by userdata? Please add any reference to that in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sessions should be used whenever you want to preserve state between two different HTTP requests.  You generally want to:

- Store session information on the server side (i.e. don't pass it all back and forth in cookies).
- Protect yourself against C[ross Site Forgery Requests](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/09/cross-site-request-forgeries-and-you.html) (CSFR) by generating a unique key for each request and validating the key when the request returns.
- Store **only** that information that will need to be accessed repeatedly. (Don't shove the 5,000+ results of the query you just ran for them into their session for example -- use caching instead.)
- Read about PHP's [`$_SESSION`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) since CodeIgniter's `session` is a wrapper around `$_SESSION`.
- Understand how to maintain a [secure session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328/php-session-security) -- and know what CodeIgniter handles for you, and what you will need to do yourself.