# How to create a safe session combined with the "Remember me" feature?

Tags: php, security, authentication, browser, ssl

I have searched the web for "how to secure a php session" and came across this [PHP Session Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328/php-session-security)

The first answer is a very good one...

I, like many others, are searching for how to create a secure "Remember me" function.

Much like the linked questions' poster, I thought it would be good to gather all information about this in one place.

If you assume I know PHP averagely, then you are correct. But I don't know much about securing PHP sessions.

Offcourse, I know how to write an unsecure "Remember me" function, which checks a cookie value (which might be hashed) against a hashed database value. If they are the same, then the user is still logged in. Simple, but dangerous!

How should I secure this "remember me" feature?

Comment: any "remember me" feature is inherently insecure.

Comment: So whats the bet if you had to have a "remember me" feature?

Comment: Why is it dangerous? You just hash the cookie value and check if the hash match in the database. If someone can access your database you have a lot more to worry than just session's safety.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of information already linked in [The Definitive Guide To Website Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-website-authentication-beta/477579#477579)

Answer (score 0):

Carefully "COOK" your cookie data. For all the rest check the complete guide on stackoverflow as Paul said, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-website-authentication-beta/477579#477579)