# PHP Session Security for Mobile Devices

Tags: php, security, session, mobile

I did see this excellent post on [PHP session Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328/php-session-security) and I wanted to know if all apply to mobile devices as well?

Is there anything that you would add/change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mobile device or non-mobile device changes nothing for PHP : PHP is executed on the server, no matter what kind of device requests the page.

As a consequence, all points given on the question/answers you linked to that are valid for a desktop browser are also valid for a mobile device.