# PHP SESSION Security question

Tags: php

Is it safe for me to use in live website?

member.php

```
if($_SESSION['login'] == 1)
//member stuff
```

`$_SESSION['login']` is set after user authenticate via login.php

Comment: Reminded me of Szell from Marathon Man...

Answer (score 1):

Session security in PHP is often asked about - see [PHP Session Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328/php-session-security) for pretty good answers.

Answer (score 1):

In general: yes. You may want to set a bit more variables, but sessions are only available to php and not the user. The part where it gets exciting in terms of security is how you handle your authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should check if $_SESSION is set too.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['login'])) { ...
    if($_SESSION['login'] == 1) { ...
```

Comment: nested ifs?  `if( isset($_SESSION['login']) && $_SESSION['login'] == 1 )` The right hand part of the expression isn't evaluated if the left hand is false, so no notice will be generated

Answer (score 0):

It's safe as the `$_SESSION` state is stored on your server, not sent back to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Using sessions is better than using cookies when checking for logins/authentication since they can be altered as it communicates with the server from client side when session are only used for server side reading.