# is there a better way of protecting specific webpages?

Tags: php, security, session, redirect

I have a website where only a user with admin privileges can view certain pages. When I login logging into my admin account `$_session["is_admin"] = true` is set. Then on the pages that I want only users with admin privileges to be able to view I check if is_admin is true else I redirect them to the index page.

`if(!$_SESSION["is_admin"]){ //redirect to index.Php}`
Is there a better way of protecting webpages in these circumstances?

Thanks

Comment: That should be fine, as long as your login script is properly secured. Also you should be using SSL (https) if security is truly important.

Comment: Make sure to kill the script after the redirect

Comment: @musa how do you mean kill the script? After the redirect takes the user to the index.php page isn't any script "killed" as soon as the page loads?

Comment: `header('Location: where ever'); exit;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relying strictly on the `$_SESSION` global is not **very** secure. There are applications capable of "hijacking" sessions and manipulating `SESSION` `ID`s which are stored client-side. Take a look at [FireSheep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firesheep).

What I would recommend would be to implement some type of extra level of security. The extra level of security could include whitelisting IP Addresses, or a short expiry time on your `SESSION`s.

Also see [is storing data in php session insecure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070744/is-storing-data-in-php-session-insecure) (it's not the same question but similar).

**White-listing IP Addresses**:

As [mentioned in white list ip address for admin access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465321/white-list-ip-address-for-admin-access), you could keep a record of the IP Addresses that have permission to access your page. If the IP Address does not fall in the allowed addresses, access to the page is denied. You can store the addresses in a database or hardcode them into the script (I'd stay away from hardcoding).

Here is a modified example taken from zerkms in the link above, incorporating your `SESSION` test:

```
$whitelist = array('192.168.0.1', '192.168.0.2');

if ($_SESSION['is_admin'] !== true || !in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $whitelist)) {
    //Admin denied.
    header('Location: denied.php'); exit();
}

echo "You're an admin!"
```

**Shorten Session Expiry Time**:

I'd recommend reading Gumbo's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes).

**More reading material**:

- http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/4.html
- http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-create-bulletproof-sessions

Comment: Thanks, could you expand on both of your suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

The code is more secure if it's somewhere not public (above public folder), so it's more difficult that problems happen. What'd happen here?

```
</php
  // Code
```

The whole page's content would be shown in plain text if it's in the public folder. While that is rare, missing a php tag is not THAT uncommon, even more in included files (and then an attacker could access that included file directly).

Also, check out this other [SO question about session hijacking](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6483092/938236), it concerns to your question directly.

EDIT. I just read the [facebook's Criticism Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criticism_of_Facebook) and is very relevant, so I quote it:

> In August 2007, the code used to generate Facebook's home and search page as visitors browse the site was accidentally made public, according to leading internet news sites. A configuration problem on a Facebook server caused the PHP code to be displayed instead of the web page the code should have created, raising concerns about how secure private data on the site was.

Had they asked this somewhere else back in the day, they might not have been exposed.

Answer (score 1):

This is OK if you only have admin and non-admin users in terms of access to pages.
You could alternatively implement roles if you have more user levels.