# symfony user parameters from a security point of view

Tags: symfony1

Where are the user parameters stored on a lower level? The filter parameters for example. I don't think it's the cookies so where is it? And is it secure? as in can a user modify them  in some way and hack his way into the website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default your session files are stored in session.savepath folder, so it's server side.
The link between this session file and the user cookie is the session_id stored inside the session cookie.

maybe you should read : [PHP Session Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328/php-session-security)

Comment: So there is some chance(if the he tries brute force), the user can find himself logged in as administrator. But then again, if you try brute force, you can even break RSA :-P.