# Cakephp saving session id in cookies, is this a secure way

Tags: php, security, session, cakephp, cookies

CakePhp saves session id in cookies, normally  cookie named  CAKEPHP contain session id
and in any other php file can start session with that id

```
session_id($_REQUEST['CAKEPHP']);
session_start();
```

my question is this a secure way of handling session id, if yes then how is it secure if now what is better solution

Comment: you can check [PHP Session Security](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/328/php-session-security) and [Sessions and security ¶](http://php.net/manual/en/session.security.php) to see how to secure session

Comment: also check [session_regenerate_id()](http://www.php.net/session_regenerate_id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The session cookie will only be valid for the same domain that generated the cookie/started the session.

Although it will be possible for another php page to pick-up that session, it will *only* receive the cookie if it is served on the same domain, in which case it is 'part' of your website.

This should therefore not be a problem, because (unless you have a serious problem) only *you* will be able to add/upload php files to your website.

You *should* check where the session DATA is saved though. The default 'php' session settings in app/Config/core.php will write the session data to the session save path that is configured in php.ini. This may be a 'shared' directory that is accessible by other websites on the same server.

For better security, set the session configuration in app/config/core.php to 'cake'. This will write the session data to app/tmp/sessions which should only be accessible by your website.