# Can phpFire access server side session variables of a live website that you don't have access to?

Tags: php, security, firebug, session-variables

Is it possible for any extensions like phpFire for Firebug to access server side session variables? Without the any access to the websites server.

I want to make sure I don't put any sensitive data into server session variables.
If not are my server side session variables safe from anything outside the server itself?

Thanks

Comment: your sessions are mostly safe, there's a few exploit options, but in most cases you can assume they are fine. Remember the actual session data is stored on your server, not the clients machine

Comment: Would you consider storing a password in a server session variable safe? A encrypted password that is.

Comment: there should never be the need to store a password in a session

Comment: But say you needed to, would you say that was unsafe?

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18991/is-it-safe-to-store-password-in-php-session http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19895925/can-i-securely-store-username-and-password-in-php-session-variables et al

Comment: I guess you are talking about ['FirePHP'](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/firephp/), not 'phpFire', right?

Comment: Yeah, FirePHP. The extension to Firebug.